# EntityCommandExecutionException in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I'm trying to make the following function work, and keep receiving a EntityCommandExecutionException error. I have no idea what the error is meaning and have been trying to fix the issue to no avail. The function is very basic...

```
    public Weeks getWeekById(int id)
    {
        Weeks week = database.Weeks.Where(w => w.id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        return week;
    }
```

Within the database I have a table called Weeks and within that two fields, a int id field and a string name field. I've even tried a 'getWeekByName' method calling the string and got the same error. I have lots of functions with exactly the same syntax working on other tables like ... 
    public Facility getFacilityById(int id){
      Facility facility = database.Facilities.Where(f => f.id == id).SingleOrDefault();
      return facility;
    }

Can anyone give me a heads up as to what's actually wrong and how I could go about fixing it?

Cheers

Comment: going to guess that this might be due to an incorrect request to the database...is it possible that id is not unique and so asking for a singleordefault would be incorrect?

Comment: Is this just LINQ to SQL or are you using some kkind of ORM.. what is  the variable `database` here??

Comment: also can you post the entire stack trace instead of just the exception type

Answer (score 1):

Try updating entity model. It may help